# VSCode doesn't show all warnings/errors

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *openFile(char const * , char const *);
int readDim(FILE *);
double **allocMatrix(int , int );
void printMatrix(int , int , double **);
void readMatrix(FILE *, int , int , double **);
void mediana(int , int , double **);
void printVect(int , double *);

FILE* openFile(char const* file_name, char const* mode)
{
  FILE* fp = fopen(file_name, mode);
  printf("File name: %s\n", file_name);
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    perror(file_name); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
  } 
  else 
    printf("File read correctly\n");

  return fp; 
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp=openFile("matrice.txt", "r");
    int nrows=readDim(fp), ncols=readDim(fp);
    printf("Rows: %d\tColumns: %d\n", nrows, ncols);
    double **matrix=allocMatrix(nrows, ncols);
    readMatrix(fp,nrows, ncols, matrix);
    printMatrix(nrows, ncols, matrix);
    mediana(nrows, ncols, matrix);
    return 0;
}

void mediana(int nrows, int ncols, double **matrix)
{
    int i, col=0;
    double temp;
    double *row=calloc(ncols, sizeof(double));
    for(i=0; i<ncols; i++)
    {
        row[i]=matrix[i][col];
    }
    printVect(ncols, row);
  /*  for(i=0; i<ncols; i++)
    {
        if(row[i]>row[i+1])
        {
            row[i]=temp;
            row[i]=row[i+1];
            row[i+1]=temp;
        }
    }    
    printVect(ncols, row);*/

}
void printVect(int ncols, double *row)
{
    int i;
    printf("Vector:\n");
    for(i=0; i<ncols; i++)
    {
        printf("%lf", row[i]);
    }
    
}
void readMatrix(FILE *fp, int nrows, int ncols, double **matrix)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<nrows; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<ncols; j++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void printMatrix(int nrows, int ncols, double **matrix)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("Matrix:\n");
    for(i=0; i<nrows; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<ncols; j++)
        {
            printf("%.4lf\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
double **allocMatrix(int nrows, int ncols)
{
    int i;
    double **matrix;
    matrix=calloc(nrows, sizeof(double));

    for(i=0; i<nrows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i]=calloc(ncols, sizeof(double));
    }

    if(matrix==NULL)
    {
        perror("matrix");
    }
    else
    printf("Memory allocated correctly\n");
    return matrix;
}

int readDim(FILE *fp)
{
    int num;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &num);
    return num;
}
```

I am sure there is some sort of error because the output i get from VSCode is:

```
File name: matrice.txt
File read correctly
Rows: 6 Columns: 8
Memory allocated correctly
Matrix:
0.8147  0.2785  0.9572  0.7922  0.6787  0.7060  0.6948  0.7655
0.9058  0.5469  0.4854  0.9595  0.7577  0.0318  0.3171  0.7952
0.1270  0.9575  0.8003  0.6557  0.7431  0.2769  0.9502  0.1869
0.9134  0.9649  0.1419  0.0357  0.3922  0.0462  0.0344  0.4898
0.6324  0.1576  0.4218  0.8491  0.6555  0.0971  0.4387  0.4456
0.0975  0.9706  0.9157  0.9340  0.1712  0.8235  0.3816  0.6463
```

TL;DR

Everything is fine until the program has to execute the "mediana" function, I think the error is `row[i]=matrix[i][col];` but the compiler doensn't show any error or warning, what should I do?

Input file:

```
6 8
0.8147    0.2785    0.9572    0.7922    0.6787    0.7060    0.6948    0.7655
0.9058    0.5469    0.4854    0.9595    0.7577    0.0318    0.3171    0.7952
0.1270    0.9575    0.8003    0.6557    0.7431    0.2769    0.9502    0.1869
0.9134    0.9649    0.1419    0.0357    0.3922    0.0462    0.0344    0.4898
0.6324    0.1576    0.4218    0.8491    0.6555    0.0971    0.4387    0.4456
0.0975    0.9706    0.9157    0.9340    0.1712    0.8235    0.3816    0.6463
```

Comment: What in the code specifically do you expect the IDE (or whatever linter) to recognize as being wrong?

Comment: @ThomasJager Ok i'll explain some other way, i have this code, inside the "mediana" function i call another function, "printVect", if i call that function before the "for" cycle inside "mediana" function, it prints the array, if i call it after the for cycle, the program "crashes", or at least, i think it crashes, the point is that the function doens't print anything

Comment: I haven't taken a close look through the code, but keep in mind that there are limits to what can be easily detected as mistakes. You can't expect every mistake you make to be caught, you have to debug yourself.

Comment: @SimoneP now [edit] and post `matrice.txt` as properly formatted text. And delete the comments you addressed to me, they are irrelevant now.

Comment: @SimoneP For myour next question please learn how to format raw text properly. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: @SimoneP Avoid size mistakes like `matrix=calloc(nrows, sizeof(double));`.  Better as `matrix=calloc(nrows, sizeof *matrix);`.

Comment: `if(matrix==NULL)` is useless as it comes after `matrix[i]=calloc(ncols, sizeof(double));`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
row[i] = matrix[i][col];
```

which should rather be:

```
row[i] = matrix[col][i];
```

You mixed up something.

You also should free the memory at the end of `mediana` with:

```
free(row);
```

BTW if you run your code with your debugger (don't ask me how to do this on your platform), your program would most likely have crashed into the debugger showing you the exact line where the crash happended.

Comment: `row[i] = matrix[i][col];` is certainly an issue.  OP using indexes like `i,j` rather than `row_i, col_i` contribute to the confusion.  It is unclear to me though that the suggested fix is correct.  Perhaps a `mediana()` re-write?